# Cassandra Seed crashed - How to rejoin?

Tags: cassandra

I have a 3-node cluster of cassandra instances.

My former seed died. I wiped the data directory and the commitlogs in hope that it will rejoin the cluster, but it didn't.

Promoting the other 2 remaining nodes as seeds didn't help, because the former seed just goes up without getting any data, but metadata. I promoted them to seeds by adding them to the "-seeds" list in cassandra.yaml

This is my log when joining:

http://pastebin.com/Z28LhA3w

192.168.81.66 is the seed. 192.168.81.68 and 192.168.81.70 are the other two nodes

Answer (score 0):

The node is already bootstrapped. Doing a repair should restore the data on that node.

Answer (score 0):

Oh lord... I deleted the wrong data directory. Node was inconsistent.